Flutter Local Notification - Notifications while the app is in background are not getting captured
Below is the main.dart file for my application. I am trying to capture the payload of my scheduled notification when the app is in background. But the app is not able to do so.
Payload capture when the app is in foreground works perfectly.
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_analytics/firebase_analytics.dart';
import 'package:firebase_analytics/observer.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:selfaffirmation/Pages/IntroScreen.dart';
import 'package:selfaffirmation/Pages/home.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
FirebaseAnalytics? analytics;
FirebaseAnalyticsObserver? observer;

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  analytics = FirebaseAnalytics.instance;
  observer = FirebaseAnalyticsObserver(analytics: analytics!);

  print('Firebase initialized');

  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  bool isFirstLaunch = prefs.getBool('is_first_launch') ?? true;
  print('SharedPreferences retrieved, isFirstLaunch: $isFirstLaunch');

  if (isFirstLaunch) {
    await prefs.setBool('is_first_launch', false);
    print('First launch, setting is_first_launch to false');
  }

  await _initializeFlutterLocalNotifications();

  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp])
      .then((value) => runApp(MyApp(isFirstLaunch: isFirstLaunch)));
}


Future<void> _initializeFlutterLocalNotifications() async {
  const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
  AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
  const InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
  InitializationSettings(android: initializationSettingsAndroid);

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
    initializationSettings,
    onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (NotificationResponse response) async {
      print('Notification clicked with payload: ${response.payload}');
      _handleNotificationClick(response.payload); //works absolutely fine
    },
    onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse: backgroundNotificationResponseHandler,   //does not work.
  );

  print('Flutter local notifications initialized');
}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> backgroundNotificationResponseHandler(NotificationResponse response) async {
  print('Background notification clicked with payload: ${response.payload}');
  _handleNotificationClick(response.payload);
}

void _handleNotificationClick(String? payload) {
  print('Handling notification click');
  print('Payload received: $payload');
  if (payload != null) {
    final parts = payload.split('_');
    if (parts.length > 2) {
      final quote = parts.sublist(2).join('_'); // Join the remaining parts to get the full quote
      print('Handling notification with quote: $quote');
      navigatorKey.currentState?.pushAndRemoveUntil(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage(quote: quote)),
            (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
      );
      print('Navigated to HomePage with quote: $quote');
    } else {
      print('Payload does not contain expected parts');
    }
  } else {
    print("Payload is null");
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isFirstLaunch;
  MyApp({Key? key, required this.isFirstLaunch}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Building MyApp widget');
    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
      home: isFirstLaunch ? IntroScreen() : HomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      navigatorObservers: [observer!],
    );
  }
}


I've avoided any multiple initialization of the local notification plugin. I have also removed FCM for the time being, incase that was interfering with the codebase (although, I don't see how that would be possible).
